# Add multiple identical homescreen widgets on Realme devices

Tags: home-screen, app-widgets, realme

On my old phone (Android 8), I used home screen widgets to take notes on the screen, it’s very convenient.

[image: Screenshot of several identical widgets]

But on my new phone (Android 10, Realme 6 pro), I get the error message “widget added”. It happens with any type of widget.

[image: Widget added error]

How can I fix this?

P.S. I'm a Python developer, but I used ADB before for fun.

Comment: Is the used note-app the same on both devices? The note icons look very different, hence it may be a limitation of the now used note app.

Comment: I use the same app and am able to add multiple notes widgets as in your left screen shot. Android 10,OnePlus 6

Answer (score 1):

In Realme UI. you can only add one widget at a time. The user can't add same widgets multiple widgets.  However there is trick, use Launchers like nova etc. Where you can add multiple widgets.
:)